# Why some HTTP proxy code are very complex, should not it be very simple?

Tags: sockets, http, proxy

I am trying to write a http proxy, and I start with looking for some code as reference. I found this and several other "lightweight" proxy examples on Github with many hundreds line of code: https://github.com/abhinavsingh/proxy.py

While I can understand the code, I wonder why these functions are necessary? Should not a HTTP proxy be very simple: one socket server accept the data from browser, one socket client establish the connection to the web server, and exchange data between the server and the client? Why should there be functions like HTTPparse() as in the example I posted?

Comment: I recommend that you take a look at the [HTTP/1.1 standard](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt). Maybe you'll get an understanding of the complexity of the protocol then and realize that a proxy is not as simple as you imagine. Notably a proxy need to detect when request/response starts to extract the target URL. It needs to know when it ends since multiple requests can be sent over the same TCP connection. This involves reading the variable sized HTTP header, getting information about the body from it and then reading the body. Also, TLS might be involved, pipelelining...

Comment: I am actually in Networking major, while I am not very familiar with HTTP in particular, I understand how it works and respect its complexity. What I don't understand is why a "proxy" should be complex, shouldn't it be just a relay between the browser and the web server, and blindlessly passes whatever imported in one end to another? Why should proxy do the parsing work?

Comment: An HTTP proxy that does nothing except relay is fairly simple, but also fairly pointless. Once you start adding useful features to it, the complexity skyrockets as it starts to have to be able to understand the protocol beyond the mere CONNECT command.

Comment: @EJP could you please just give one example? What is a "useful feature", and what other "protocols" a proxy needs to understand?

Comment: If you want it to log, or filter, or cache, or authenticate, or rewrite, it will have to understand *the HTTP protocol* beyond the mere CONNECT command and its response.

Comment: Thanks for quoting "proxy.py".  Like most projects, "proxy.py" was initially an implementation written in a single file with about 600-700 lines of code.  Here is the link to the first commit https://github.com/abhinavsingh/proxy.py/commit/75044a72d9c7b4b8910ba551006b801eafdf3c47.  But as it turned out over the years, "proxy.py" is now more of a framework than just a proxy server.  Much more infact, and hence the complexity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A real HTTP proxy is not just a software which accepts a connection from a client and forwards this connection to a fixed server.

Instead, an HTTP proxy needs to first extract the target from the HTTP request sent by the client. In order to do this, the proxy needs to parse the HTTP request header. It also needs to modify the header in order to change an HTTP proxy request into an HTTP request, which involves mainly removing the `protocol://host:port` from the URI and keep the rest. But it might also involve adding a `Via` header. Also, a proxy might require its own authentication, in which case this information needs to be extracted, verified, and removed from the HTTP request header, too.

Since multiple HTTP requests (also to different servers) might be sent inside the same TCP connection to the proxy, the proxy needs to parse all requests. This means that it needs to know where a request starts and ends. Given that both request header and body are variable size, the proxy needs to read the full header first, analyze it to get information about the size of the body and then read and forward the body accordingly (i.e. fixed length set by the `Content-Length` header, chunked transfer encoding, or end of connection). The response from the server must be handled in the same way.

Additionally to that, the proxy needs to be able to handle HTTP `CONNECT` requests so that the client can build a tunnel for `https://` connections, and even other protocols.

This is only the basic proxy functionality. A proxy might also be used to cache data, in which case it needs to be able to understand the various ways of when and how data can be cached, and when caching is not allowed. It might need to work around quirks with specific client or servers. It might be used to intercept TLS, modify the traffic, etc...

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation!